# SmartOS not recognizing my keyboard upon installation

Tags: smartos, omnios

I bought a homeserver and wanted to install SmartOS... I have a Roccat ISKU USB-Keyboard which is working at the startup (can enter bios) and I can also choose the startup option via this keyboard..  `Live 64-bit (text)`
After choosing this option it takes a long time for anything else to happen and then there is a warning:

```
Warning: kvm: no hardware support
```

then the startup continues until I have to say "yes" continue with configuration..
I cannot type anything here? what am I doing wrong?

the same (with the same error msg) holds for omniOS

Comment: From http://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Hardware+Requirements : USB3 is not currently supported by illumos. You may need to disable it in your BIOS.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such option in the bios of my system (hp microserver).. And I don't think that the keyboard has usb3.0 as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it with another keyboard and it works.. so the issue is the used Roccat ISKU keyboard..